# Decrypt strange encoded characters in the attribute table of a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, encode

In QGIS, I can't read characters of the shapefile in my geological layer attribute table : I don't understand or there are misunderstandable characters of shapefile.

Below a screenshot of the attribute table.. Does anyone know how I could get the original values back ?

[image: screenshot of table of attributes of the geological map]

Comment: Please choose one software package, then research support for UTF-8 strings and international character support, then [edit] this question to specify what you have attempted.

Comment: Create a .cpg file using a text editor with the same name of the layer(e.g. geological_map.cpg),  and insert the Unicode encoding identifier `UTF-8' into it.

Comment: I think it is quite easy the aswer for this question, I do not agree with having it on hold. The answer for a QGIS user is just going to Layer Properties->General->Data source encoding and look for the right encoding, many times UTF-8 fix it

Comment: @AmitGhosh (or Marco) You should post your comments as answers now the subject has been reopened

Comment: Please open the .cpg file with a text editor and tell us what is inside.

Answer (score 8):

As @Marco mentioned in the comment, look for the right encoding by changing the data source encoding from the layer properties window. The most probable choice is  `UTF-8`

[image]

Most of the modern GIS softwares (including QGIS and ArcGIS) store the encoding information in an optional .cpg (code page)file. Therefore, you should create the same manually with proper encoding identifier (as mentioned in the comment) To create a .cpg file automatically in QGIS save (right click on the layer>save as) the layer and select the proper encoding. Then QGIS/ArcGIS will detect the proper encoding.

[image]

Comment: What if UTF-8 doesn't work as the encoding?  I have a file that I have tried multiple different encodings and none of them convert the accents into the characters I would expect. How can I find the correct one?

Comment: I've same problem but in QGIS 3.4 in Linux (LMDE 3) Debian 9, Do you know how can I fix that I checked my ESRI Shapefiles layers are in UTF-8 by default

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem and fixed it. 
After following Amit's suggestion, you may also need to click on the "Menu -> Settings -> Options -> Data Sources", where you can uncheck "Ignore shapefile encoding declaration". Then, restart your project. This worked for me.

[image: setting menu]